# Yii2 restful api without page limit

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Am using `yii\rest\ActiveController` without pagelimit

This is how am doing it

```
<?php

namespace rest\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class CompanyController extends ActiveController
   {
   public $modelClass = 'frontend\models\TblDeliveredCompanies';

 }
```

The above returns only 20 records how do i improve it to return all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override prepareDataProvider() inside the controller to return a custom data provider from index action:

```
public function prepareDataProvider()
{
    $query = \frontend\models\TblDeliveredCompanies::find();
    $dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
         'query' => $query,
         'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 0]
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Check documentation at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-controllers.html#extending-active-controller

Answer (score 1):

The limit for 20 could be related to the default pagination values for dataProvider so in your controller/action or in the model where the $dataProvider is create  you shoul redefine the function assign the pagination as false

```
$dataProvider->pagination = false;
```

or

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
   'query' => $your_query,
     'pagination' => false,
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the code in the model class `'TblDeliveredCompanies'` present at `'frontend\models\TblDeliveredCompanies'` it must have the SQL query containing the limit 20, change it to `'SELECT * from yourtbl where %yourcond%'`

Answer (score 0):

Other solution

```
public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions();
    $actions['index']['pagination'] = false;
    return $actions;
}
```